# How to get data from textview and checkboxes from dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have create an `EditText` button which opens a dialog with bunch of checkboxes and one EditText. In the `OnCreate` method:

```
        skillsEditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_skills);
        skillsEditText.setClickable(true);
        skillsEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_adding_skills,null);
                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                specialSkillsDialog = mBuilder.create();
                specialSkillsDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                specialSkillsDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

**After** the users clicks Done, I execute the `onDoneClick` method:

```
    public void onProfessionsDoneClick(View view) {
        CheckBox skillCheckBox1 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_skill1);
        if (skillCheckBox1.isChecked()) {
            allSkills.add(skillCheckBox1.getText().toString());
        }

        // Other checkboxes
        // ...
        TextView textInDialog = findViewById(R.id.edit_custom_text);
        // more code
    }
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
```

From previous threads I learn that those checkboxes and edittext are in the dialog so I can't get them from the `MainActivity`. What is the best way there to change so it will work?

Comment: which view is passed in onProfessionsDoneClick? If its the view of the dialog then just change it to CheckBox skillCheckBox1 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_skill1)

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link them to your dialog.

I.e

```
skillCheckbox1 = specialSkillsDialog.findViewById(R.id.someId)
```

do this prior to making the call for IsChecked();

Answer (score 0):

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
>   android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference

**`NullPointerException`** is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference that has the null value.

If **`onProfessionsDoneClick(View view)`** view coming from Dialog section then pass View's object.

```
 public void onProfessionsDoneClick(View view) {
        CheckBox skillCheckBox1 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_skill1);
        if (skillCheckBox1.isChecked()) {
            allSkills.add(skillCheckBox1.getText().toString());
        }

        // Other checkboxes
        // ...
        TextView textInDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_custom_text);
        // more code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need link the view to your checkbox

```
CheckBox skillCheckBox1 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_skill1);
```